# Stuck with the oracle Ref cursor in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am using oracle database with Node.js. I am calling a Stored procedure from Node.js that returns multiple REF cursors. When I am trying to fetch the rows from cursor it is giving some absurd integer value. Here is my code...

```js
async function retrievePNRContext(req, res) {
    const reservationInfo = req.body.ReservationInfo;const p_series_num = reservationInfo.SeriesNumber;
    const p_confirmation_num = reservationInfo.ConfirmationNumber;const p_last_load_guid = uuid.v1();
    const p_view_only = "false";const p_reservation_required = "true";const p_payment_required = "true";
    const p_oa_flights_required = "true";const p_comments_required = "true";const p_history_required = "true";
    const p_segments_required = "true";const p_person_required = "true";const p_segment_person_map_required = "true";
    const p_seat_assignments_required = "true";const p_apis_info_required = "true";const p_price_info_required = "true";
    const p_charge_required = "true";const p_res_payment_map_required = "true";const p_physical_flt_info_required = "true";
    const p_res_contacts_required = "true";const p_contact_info_required = "true";const p_cpginprogress_pmnt_required = "true";
    const p_group_name_override_flag = 0;const p_block_pnr_retrieval_flag = 0;const p_reservation = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_payment = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_oa_flights = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_comments = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_history = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_segments = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_person = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_segment_person_map = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_seat_assignments = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_apis_info = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_price_info = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_charge = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_res_payment_map = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_physical_flight_Info = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_res_contacts = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_contact_info = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_cpginprogress_payment = oracledb.CURSOR
    try {
        oracledb.prefetchRows = 10000;oracledb.maxRows = 400000;oracledb.fetchArraySize = 10000000;
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbconfig);
        console.log(dbconfig);
        console.log('Connection successful');
        var sql ='BEGIN KRISHNA_TEST.SP_RETRIEVE_RESERVATION(:p_series_num, :p_confirmation_num, :p_last_load_guid, :p_view_only,\
 :P_reservation_required, :P_payment_required, :P_oa_flights_required, :p_comments_required, :p_history_required, :p_segments_required,\
 :p_person_required, :p_segment_person_map_required, :p_seat_assignments_required, :p_apis_info_required, :p_price_info_required, :p_charge_required,\
 :p_res_payment_map_required, :p_physical_flt_info_required, :p_res_contacts_required, :p_contact_info_required, :p_cpginprogress_pmnt_required, :p_group_name_override_flag,\
 :p_block_pnr_retrieval_flag, :p_reservation, :p_payment, :p_oa_flights, :p_comments, :p_history, :p_segments, :p_person, :p_segment_person_map, :p_seat_assignments, \
 :p_apis_info, :p_price_info, :p_charge, :p_res_payment_map, :p_physical_flight_info, :p_res_contacts, :p_contact_info, :p_cpginprogress_payment); END;';
 var bindvars = {
            p_series_num: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_series_num },
            p_confirmation_num: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_confirmation_num },
            p_last_load_guid: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_last_load_guid },
            p_view_only: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_view_only },
            P_reservation_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_reservation_required },
            P_payment_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_payment_required },
            P_oa_flights_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_oa_flights_required },
            p_comments_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_comments_required },
            p_history_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_history_required },
            p_segments_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_segments_required },
            p_person_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_person_required },
            p_segment_person_map_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_segment_person_map_required },
            p_seat_assignments_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_seat_assignments_required },
            p_apis_info_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_apis_info_required },
            p_price_info_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_price_info_required },
            p_charge_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_charge_required },
            p_res_payment_map_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_res_payment_map_required },
            p_physical_flt_info_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_physical_flt_info_required },
            p_res_contacts_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_res_contacts_required },
            p_contact_info_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_contact_info_required },
            p_cpginprogress_pmnt_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_cpginprogress_pmnt_required },
            p_group_name_override_flag: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_group_name_override_flag },
            p_block_pnr_retrieval_flag: { type: oracledb.NUMBER, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_block_pnr_retrieval_flag },
            p_reservation: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_payment: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_oa_flights: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_comments: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_history: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_segments: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_person: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_segment_person_map: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_seat_assignments: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_apis_info: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_price_info: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_charge: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_res_payment_map: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_physical_flight_Info: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_res_contacts: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_contact_info: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 },
            p_cpginprogress_payment: { type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, maxSize: 10000000 }
        };
        await connection.execute(sql, bindvars, function (err, result) {
            if (err) console.log(err.message);
            const rows = result.outBinds['p_reservation'];
            console.log(rows);
            rows.getRows(numRows, function (err, row) {
                if (err) console.log(err.message);
                row.forEach(r => console.log(r));
            });        

        });       
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    finally {
        //cleanup
    }

};
```

Please let me know how to get rows from cursor in Node.js..Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you implemented the same method as this example? https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/node-oracledb-070-now-supports-result-sets-and-ref-cursors

Comment: Yes Nick...almost tried the same thing but not getting the rows from the cursor..I am getting the result as [ [ 1 ] ]...Please help!!

Comment: Where are you seeing this result? Are you getting an error? Please explain the contents of all the variables in your code. Have you successfully done this for a non-refcursor proc from node?

Comment: Should your code be `rows = result.outBinds["p_reservation"].cursor;` I'm not a node guy, this is just a suggestion from comparing code.

Comment: Please find the complete code below:

Comment: async function retrievePNRContext(req, res) {
    const reservationInfo = req.body.ReservationInfo;const p_series_num = reservationInfo.SeriesNumber;
    const p_confirmation_num = reservationInfo.ConfirmationNumber;const p_last_load_guid = uuid.v1();
    const p_view_only = "false";const p_reservation_required = "true";const p_payment_required = "true";
    const p_oa_flights_required = "true";const p_comments_required = "true";const p_history_required = "true";
    const p_segments_required = "true";const p_person_required = "true";const p_segment_person_map_required = "true";

Comment: const p_seat_assignments_required = "true";const p_apis_info_required = "true";const p_price_info_required = "true";
    const p_charge_required = "true";const p_res_payment_map_required = "true";const p_physical_flt_info_required = "true";
    const p_res_contacts_required = "true";const p_contact_info_required = "true";const p_cpginprogress_pmnt_required = "true";
    const p_group_name_override_flag = 0;const p_block_pnr_retrieval_flag = 0;const p_reservation = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_payment = oracledb.CURSOR;

Comment: const p_oa_flights = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_comments = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_history = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_segments = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_person = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_segment_person_map = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_seat_assignments = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_apis_info = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_price_info = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_charge = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_res_payment_map = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_physical_flight_Info = oracledb.CURSOR;
    const p_res_contacts = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_contact_info = oracledb.CURSOR;const p_cpginprogress_payment = oracledb.CURSOR

Comment: try {
        oracledb.prefetchRows = 10000;oracledb.maxRows = 400000;oracledb.fetchArraySize = 10000000;
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbconfig);
        console.log(dbconfig);
        console.log('Connection successful');
        var sql ='BEGIN KRISHNA_TEST.SP_RETRIEVE_RESERVATION(:p_series_num, :p_confirmation_num, :p_last_load_guid, :p_view_only,\
 :P_reservation_required, :P_payment_required, :P_oa_flights_required, :p_comments_required, :p_history_required, :p_segments_required,\

Comment: :p_person_required, :p_segment_person_map_required, :p_seat_assignments_required, :p_apis_info_required, :p_price_info_required, :p_charge_required,\
 :p_res_payment_map_required, :p_physical_flt_info_required, :p_res_contacts_required, :p_contact_info_required, :p_cpginprogress_pmnt_required, :p_group_name_override_flag,\
 :p_block_pnr_retrieval_flag, :p_reservation, :p_payment, :p_oa_flights, :p_comments, :p_history, :p_segments, :p_person, :p_segment_person_map, :p_seat_assignments, \

Comment: :p_apis_info, :p_price_info, :p_charge, :p_res_payment_map, :p_physical_flight_info, :p_res_contacts, :p_contact_info, :p_cpginprogress_payment); END;';

Comment: var bindvars = {
            p_series_num: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_series_num },
            p_confirmation_num: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_confirmation_num },
            p_last_load_guid: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_last_load_guid },
            p_view_only: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_view_only },
            P_reservation_required: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: p_reservation_required },

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code in there. There's no way anyone can make sense of bulk code in comments.

Comment: updated the code in the original question...

Comment: To start, this makes no sense: `await connection.execute(sql, bindvars, function (err, result) {...` You're either using callbacks or async/await. You need to choose one or the other. Read this to learn more about the options: https://jsao.io/2017/06/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-various-async-patterns/

Comment: Also, why on earth would your stored procedure return so many cursors? Would any of these ever have more than one row? p_reservation, p_payment, p_person. There are many more that look like they should be returning record types (single records) rather than cursors. Some of the "maps" should probably be simplified too. How do you know which cursors will return single rows vs multiple?

Comment: Hi Dan...the stored procedure has been shared by the client and we need to use it..While calling the SP it is not giving any error but I am unable to fetch the rows from the cursors...Please help.

Comment: There's been two suggestion in the comments so far. Why don't you try some of those before requesting further help

Comment: Hi Nick...I have tried these suggestions already but it's not working.

Comment: "the stored procedure has been shared by the client and we need to use it". Okay, fine. I want you to tell me, for each cursor returned, will you get one or more rows. You should have this information. Also, you said something about an "absurd integer". Where are you sing this? Generally, this would result from an Oracle Number (decimal) to JavaScript Number (no decimal). The only workaround would be to fetch the numbers out as strings.

Comment: Thank you guys!! there was a silly mistake in my code that's why I was unable to fetch the rows...The stored procedure was expecting a boolean flag in upper case and  was using lower case...